# Get Microsoft Graph API Calendar published URL

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have a requirement where I need to access publicly shared URL of a calendar(also want to share calendar using the API) using microsoft graph api. But it seems like its not available using GraphServiceClient. What Im trying to achieve is

```
        var cal = await graphClient...<anything>....Calendar.Request(options).GetAsync();
        if(cal.CanShare.HasValue && cal.CanShare.Value)
        {
            // get the published URL of the calendar here
        }
```

Comment: you're doing `graphClient.Me` how's that publicly available? that resource is specific to your account

Comment: @Aarif Yes even if thats specific to my account, the published calendar URL is accessible from anywhere and its not implemented with graphclient. I can access any user's calendar using user id .

Answer (score 0):

It seems the center point here is that you're expecting /Me/Calendars to include shared calendars. It does not. In order to access someone else's calendar that has been shared, you must access via the `/Users/<id>/Calendars/` URL.

So for example if **`user1@fabrikam.com`** logs in, and user2@fabrikam.com has shared his calendar with him/her, then:

1. `/Me/Calendars` would ONLY show calendars in User1 mailbox.
2. /Users/user2@contoso.com/Calendars would show calendars user2 has shared with user1

Hope it helps.

Comment: Question is about getting published Calendar link. That could be my calendar also. THe above code is just representational